# Turning a nested array into an object with reduce

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

There's an exercise I was working with that asked for a function to create a nested array into an object.

Example input: `[['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]]`
Expected output: `{ make: 'Ford', model: 'Mustan', year: 1969 }`

I attempted it by writing this:

```
function fromListToObject(array) {
    let obj = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        obj[arr[i][0]] = arr[i][1];
    }
}
```

But that didn't work, so I found another solution and it used reduce:

```
function fromListToObject(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc[curr[0]] = curr[1];
    return acc;
}, {});
}
```

Now I thought I understood how reduce worked but never really messed with it for objects, how does `acc[curr[0]]` work? It starts out as an empty object and but i'm confused as to what `acc` is after the first iteration. Can anyone explain please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What didn't work with the first one?  Did you get an error?  If not, what was the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"Now I thought I understood how reduce worked but never really messed with it for objects, how does `acc[curr[0]]` work?"*

`acc` is always the return value from the previous iteration (or on the first iteration, the starting value if provided, else the first array element).

So because you're always returning `acc`, which is the `{}` you started with, then `acc` is always that starting object.

And `curr` is the current item from the array, which is the sub-array holding the key and value you're adding to the `acc` object.

Comment: Gotcha, I feel like I understand what is happening, it's just the syntax of it is throwing me off:

`acc[curr[0]] = curr[1];` acc before the first iteration is `{}`, then after the first one, `acc[curr[0]]` is `make` so `[curr[0]]` is technically `make `it just sets it as a key in `acc`. Am I making sense? Not sure how to articulate my thoughts here.

EDIT: OOOOOH nevermind. I understand now.

Comment: @user7496931: Yep, I hear you. FYI, you can use `Object.assign` and the new expression evaluation syntax to reduce the callback to one line. `return Object.assign(acc, {[curr[0]]: curr[1]})`

Comment: ...yeah I think you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array` as variable name and return the `obj`.

```js
function fromListToObject(array) {
    let obj = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        obj[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(fromListToObject([['make', 'Ford'], ['model', 'Mustang'], ['year', 1964]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Reduce gives your callback function an object. Then your callback function needs to return an object, which then gets passed into your callback again on the next iteration. So just like with an array you can modify your object as you see fit.

So in short, in the first iteration of reduce the `acc` variable is the object that you pass in to the second arg of the reduce function. But for every iteration after that the value of `acc` is the value returned by your callback in the previous iteration.

Answer (score 0):

[reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) applies the function you pass to it to every element of a given list. The function receives the element and the accumulator. At the end you get one result.

So a simple case is something like `reduce([1,2,3], +, 0)`, would just sum the values, as the accumulator would start as 0 and then sum each element to it.

In your case the accumulator is an object, so when you iterate over the first element it would be something like this:

```
acc = {}
element = ['make', 'ford']
```

and so you change the accumulator by using `element[0]` as the key, and `element[1]` as the value, converting `acc` to `{ make: 'ford' }`.

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` takes a function and an initial value.  The function is called for each element in the array and returns the result for that step.  The first call is passed the initial value passed to reduce() and each other call is passed the result of the previous function call.

So in your case it expands like this (where f is the function you pass):

```
let default = {};
let a = f(['make', 'Ford'], default); // initial call uses default value
let b = f(['model', 'Mustang'], a); // uses result of previous call
let c = f(['year', '1964'], b);
```

Since you are returning a reference to the same object you are passed, default, a, b, and c will all be references to the same object.  You are modifying the object at each step so that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

your first function looks like it would work in the format you went with, I think it didn't work because the variable name `arr` doesn't exist. it should be `array` the parameter you pass in to the function.

```
function fromListToObject(array) {
  let obj = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    obj[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
  }
}
```